# AirDrop Not working - Missing Settings

Tags: macos, airdrop

I can't get AirDrop to work on my machine running OSX 10.11.4 (trying to send file to and from iPhone 6s)

I'm missing the bottom menu that reads `"Allow me to be discovered by..."`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Has this worked on previous versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you meet the minimum requirements?

> To send items to an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, you need a 2012 or newer Mac model with OS X Yosemite or later, excluding the Mac Pro (Mid 2012).

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT203106

Comment: Mine's a 2010... that's all sorts of derpy.